# Video file is not playing through IIS server

Tags: asp.net, html, iis-6

I have added the html 5 video tag in my web page. The video is running (locally) on an IIS server which is the hosting machine. But when I run through the domain name it's not running (outside of IIS).

Folder permission is also given, but it runs from IIS Local.

I added the mime type on the IIS server.

```
var video = document.getElementById('videotag'); 
video.src =   '../Images/Videos/example.webm';
video.play();
```

Comment: The title and body of your question seem to contradict: *"is not playing through IIS"* versus *"it's not running outside of IIS"*. Could you improve the question?

Comment: If your type is MP4 on IIS with .NET add a mime type.

Answer (score 0):

There is only a single way to do this currently. If your type of video is MP4 running on IIS/.NET

Add a web.config file to the root of the application `wwwroot\web.config` with the following contents

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <configuration>
    <system.webServer>
      <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="application/mp4" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
      </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
  </configuration>
```